# How to edit my script to target specific HTML text in div

Tags: javascript, html, css, npm, ms-word

I am just learning how to code .I am working a text generator that will allow users to edit text and export it as `.DOCX` and I found this script [jsfiddl](https://jsfiddle.net/talabe/qaun4phj/1/) on this website [npmjs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/docx) and this script allow to export HTML to `.DOCX` but I could not figure out how to make this script export HTML text in a specific `div` and for my example export content in `<div id="exportContent">` ?

N.B: When I tried to organize the script in jsfiddl as html and javascript it did not work.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/docx@4.0.0/build/index.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/FileSaver.js/1.3.8/FileSaver.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

    <h1>DOCX browser Word document generation</h1>

    <button type="button" onclick="generate()">Click to generate document</button>

    <script>
        function generate() {
            const doc = new Document();

            const paragraph = new Paragraph("Hello World");
            const institutionText = new TextRun("Foo Bar").bold();
            const dateText = new TextRun("Github is the best").tab().bold();
            paragraph.addRun(institutionText);
            paragraph.addRun(dateText);

            doc.addParagraph(paragraph);

            const packer = new Packer();

            packer.toBlob(doc).then(blob => {
                console.log(blob);
                saveAs(blob, "example.docx");
                console.log("Document created successfully");
            });
        }
    </script>

<div id="exportContent">
   Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.
   Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, 
   <span  class="a" contenteditable="true" >
  -----------------YOUR TEXT HERE--------------------
    </span> took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. 
   It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. 
   It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages,
   and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
</div>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to export the HTML in `#exportContent`, pass the innerHTML of `#exportContent` to your doc.

```js
function generate() {
    const doc = new Document();
    
    // this is what you want to export
    let exportThis = document.getElementById("exportContent").innerHTML
    
    const paragraph = new Paragraph(exportThis);

    doc.addParagraph(paragraph);

    const packer = new Packer();

    packer.toBlob(doc).then(blob => {
        console.log(blob);
        saveAs(blob, "example.docx");
        console.log("Document created successfully");
    });
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/docx@4.0.0/build/index.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/FileSaver.js/1.3.8/FileSaver.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

    <h1>DOCX browser Word document generation</h1>

    <button type="button" onclick="generate()">Click to generate document</button>


  <div id="exportContent">
     Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.
     Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, 
     <span  class="a" contenteditable="true" >
    -----------------YOUR TEXT HERE--------------------
      </span> took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. 
     It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. 
     It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages,
     and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

If you want your users to be able to edit text though, you'll need to use something else than a `<div>`.

```js
function generate() {
    const doc = new Document();
    
    // this is what you want to export
    let exportThis = document.getElementById("exportContent").value
    
    const paragraph = new Paragraph(exportThis);

    doc.addParagraph(paragraph);

    const packer = new Packer();

    packer.toBlob(doc).then(blob => {
        console.log(blob);
        saveAs(blob, "example.docx");
        console.log("Document created successfully");
    });
}
```

```css
textarea {
  margin-top:2em;
  width:100%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/docx@4.0.0/build/index.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/FileSaver.js/1.3.8/FileSaver.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

    <h1>DOCX browser Word document generation</h1>

    <button type="button" onclick="generate()">Click to generate document</button>


<textarea id="exportContent">
  -----------------Whatever you type here will be exported--------------------


</textarea>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I am really grateful for your answer but I want to export html text as word document with html formatting but without tags I already have a [script](https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=G53TWQOBEULP) that allowed me to edit text and export it but the problem is ,it gets exported as `.doc` only not `.docx` and result page is `web layout` instead of `A4` and `Portrait` and when I found this new script I got hope to export HTML text as `.docx` and `A4` and `Portrait` so how can I export text without tags like or how can I edit my old script to make it done and thanks for help .